# Add a legend to geom_smooth that does not have an aes aesthetic call

Tags: r, ggplot2

Consider the following:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, mpg)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_smooth(aes(color = factor(cyl)), se = FALSE, method = "lm") +
  geom_smooth(se = FALSE, method = "lm", fullrange = TRUE, color = "black")
```

[image: Plot]

Is it possible to add a scale or legend for the black line? Something like:

[image: Desired Results]

Comment: You need to map something instead of setting the color outside aes, e.g., aes(color = "All data").

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just add another `aes` mapping in the second `geom_smooth()` call:

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, mpg)) +
     geom_point(aes(color = factor(cyl)), show.legend = FALSE) +
     geom_smooth(aes(color = factor(cyl)), se = FALSE, method = "lm") +
     geom_smooth(se = FALSE, method = "lm", fullrange = TRUE,
                 aes(color = "all data")) +
     scale_color_manual(values = c(scales::hue_pal()(3), "black"))
print(p)
```

[image: plot]

Comment: perfect - was over thinking it.

Answer (score 3):

The legend for all data can be separated out from the `cyl` color legends with the following trick with `scale_fill_identity` and using `fill` instead of `color` for the all-data `geom_smooth`:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, mpg, color = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(se = FALSE, method = "lm") +
  geom_smooth(data=mtcars, aes(disp, mpg, fill = 'black'), se = FALSE, method = "lm", color='black') + 
  scale_fill_identity(name = '', guide = 'legend',labels = c('all data'))
```

[image]